# Clipping Lines Using Expression in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, line, clip, function

I have a set of roads that I wish to clip. How ever I only need a segment of each road based on the state its located in. I can do this independently but seems like there should be a better way.

Ill try to explain it as best as I can:

I have road A, B AND C. I have states 1, 2 and 3.

All 3 roads run by all each of the states. However, I need to export only the part of road A within state 2, the part of road B within state 1 and the part of road C within state 3.

Hope its not too confusing. In reality i'm dealing with municipalities, not states but I feel this is a simpler way of explaining it.

Using QGIS 3.4 MADERIA

Comment: Is the use of 'expression' **mandatory** ? it's in your title not in the body of your question ...

Answer (score 3):

Using Expression in QGIS **Geometry by Expression** tool -

Provided:

- Road layername is `roads` and it has `road_no` field to represent the road name (A, B, C)
- State layername is `states` and it has `state_no` field (1, 2, 3)

[image]

Start **Geometry by expression** tool in the *QGIS Processing toolbox - Vector geometry*

Select your `roads` layer as input `(1)`, and choose `Line` as geometry type `(2)`, then click on the epsilon mark `(3)`.

[image]

Try an expression in the `Expression Dialog` window:

```
combine(
 combine(
  intersection(geometry(get_feature( 'roads',  'road_no', 'A')),
               geometry(get_feature('states', 'state_no', '2'))),
  intersection(geometry(get_feature( 'roads',  'road_no', 'B')),  
               geometry(get_feature('states', 'state_no', '1')))
  ),
  intersection(geometry(get_feature( 'roads',  'road_no', 'C')),  
               geometry(get_feature('states', 'state_no', '3')))
)
```

[image]

It will return a new temporally layer, *Modified geometry*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you need the solution using expression only. However I suggest to use the option

> Intersect

this operation in QGIS to generate the lines separately crossing in each state/multiplicity polygons. The lines will have the attributes from the respective state polygon.

[image]

Results as below:

[image]